# Routing error with ASP.Net and AngularJS: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set up an AngularJS application with a ASP.Net MVC server-side framework on a MacBook Air with Xamarin. I am moving from a Node.js runtime environment to ASP.Net and I cannot figure out how the routing is supposed to work with Angular.

I want to have a single route on the server-side and let all the other routes be controlled by Angular on the client side. However I keep getting this message:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. angular.min.js?_=1466979148289:290
>   WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

I know Angular is being loaded more than once, so how would I set the Angular application as I'd like it? The relevant code is below:

***Server-Side***

**App_Start/routeconfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                url: "{*.}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/index.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" class="main-guy">

    <div ui-view></div>

</div>
```

***Client-Side***

**Scripts/javascripts/app.js**

```
angular.module('app').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('', '/main')
        .when('/', '/main')
        .otherwise(function($injector){
            $injector.get('$state').go('404', {}, { location: false });
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('main',{
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/main',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .state('freeplay',{
            url: '/freeplay',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/freeplay',
            controller: 'FreeplayController'
        })
        .state('404', {
            url:'/404',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/404'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```

**Directory structure**

[image: Directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer: didn't complete my route filenames so it was an endless loop:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('main',{
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/main.cshtml',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .state('freeplay',{
            url: '/freeplay',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/freeplay.cshtml',
            controller: 'FreeplayController'
        })
        .state('404', {
            url:'/404',
            templateUrl: 'Views/Route/404.cshtml'
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question. Instead, this will be alternative approach to implement ASP.Net MVC with AngularJs.

I personally like  Miguel A Castro's Mini SPA (Silos). You can watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f67PFtrldGQ), and download the source at his [website](http://www.melvicorp.com/downloads.html).

What it does is when a request comes in, it goes to ASP.Net MVC Route first. Then, Angular Route takes over the rest. It is a very slick design.

***FYI:*** Angular 2 is right around the corner, so you want to use Angular 1.5 Compotent as much as possible so that you can convert to Angular 2 easily later.

Comment: Will keep that in mind for next time. Luckily, this is an application that doesn't need to be updated in the future! But I do agree, I should study Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to load your script to your view. After that you have to create div with ng-app, ng-controller and ng-view. You can go in detail through this link given below.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/mvc-routing-with-angularjs-routing/